# Not Found Error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ejs, file-not-found

I am new in NodeJS and I am trying to build an ecommerce application. I have readymade design and all the front end things with angularjs code. If I'm clicking on any menu then the page content changes along with the URL and is working fine but the problem is when I reload that page it shows me '**Not Found**' error.

***Internally loaded view***

[image]

***On reloading the Page***

[image]

**Note**:- Error shows 106 line of app.js file but it simply contains the error printing statement that is "var err = new Error('Not Found');".

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you are trying to get page with route you have not.

Comment: HTTP 404 means that you tried to access a route that does not have a handler.

Comment: But internally all pages works fine. If required then where I've to write all the routes??

Comment: You would have to define the routes in `app.js`

Answer (score 1):

you call the wrong route, the route is not defined on server that's why it gives you 404 error

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html
personally i follow this structure, i hope it helps you